# VBA Macro to compare then organize data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to architect a macro to do the following steps:

1. Compare two lists of data (in this case Column A against Column C)

[image]

2. Output in B any cell that exists in both A and C. Line up the match next to its match in Column A.

[image]

3. Sort both column A and B by their values so that the corresponding cells in A and B are still next to each other after the sort.

[image]

Desired result. Notice how the matches in column A and B are still together. This enables users of this macro to quickly eliminate data that only belongs to one of the respective columns *and* it allows us to retain any information that may be tied to column A, e.g., Column A contains email addresses, and there is a corresponding column next to it that contains phone #'s. We don't want to split that information up. This macro would enable that:

Pastebin of excel data I used: http://pastebin.com/mYuQRMjj

[image: Desired result]

This is the macro I've written, which uses a second macro:

```
Sub Macro()

        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Application.Run "macro4.xlsm!Find_Matches"
        Range("B1:B284").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B284") _
             , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
             .SetRange Range("A1:B284")
             .Header = xlGuess
             .MatchCase = False
             .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
             .SortMethod = xlPinYin
             .Apply

    End With

End Sub
```

The second macro that does the comparison is literally ripped straight from Microsoft, with a little extra.

```
Sub Find_Matches()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
     ' Set CompareRange equal to the range to which you will
     ' compare the selection.
     Set CompareRange = Range("C1:C500")
     ' NOTE: If the compare range is located on another workbook
     ' or worksheet, use the following syntax.
     ' Set CompareRange = Workbooks("Book2"). _
     '   Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C5")
     '
     ' Loop through each cell in the selection and compare it to
     ' each cell in CompareRange.
     For Each x In Selection
         For Each y In CompareRange
             If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 1) = x
         Next y
     Next x
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Using these two macros, I get exactly what I want, but I **don't** like using limited ranges. I want the macro to be smart enough to determine exactly what the range is, because the people who will be using this macro sometimes will be using a list of 200, sometimes a list of 2,000,000. I want this macro to be a "one size fits all" for range.

I looked into this and the command:

```
Range(Range("B1"),Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
```

gets exactly the selection I want after Find_Matches runs (I also realize that Find_Matches is using a finite compare range . . . solving my issue for this first Macro will solve that too).

**The problem is that I am unsure how to plug that into my Macro**. I've tried several implementations and I'm flat out stuck. I can't find an answer for something this specific, but I know I'm very close. Thank you for any help!

*edit*: This whole method is *realllly* slow on larger lists (20+ minutes on a list of 100k). If you can suggest some ways to speed it up that would be super helpful!

Comment: If your sheets are clean of shapes then you can simply use `Worksheet.UsedRange.Columns("A:C")` for the range.

Comment: @jbarker2160 that runs the risk of having blank cells that Excel remembers you using and considers part of the `UsedRange`.

Comment: But it looks like this is a data dump, so it shouldn't be a problem with virgin data.

Comment: @CharlesSeverson Do columns `A` and `C` have the same number of rows?

Comment: @jbarker2160 unless a raw data file is copied/imported into a workbook that has the macro and is rerun regularly.

Comment: And without user intervention there can be no blank remembered cells...

Comment: @Degustaf, with the code he's using a few extra, blank rows will make abosolutely 0 difference to the outcome.

Comment: @Degustaf, good question. No. Ideally A will be shorter than C, as you are essentially asking the question "I have a small list A and a big list C, put whatever is in both in B". B and A could theoretically be the same length if every member of A was also in C.

Comment: I'll throw in a couple pictures to show exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Pictures added. The macro should do all of those steps . . . and it does in it's current form, but I'd like for the range to be **unbounded**, so I don't have to manually change the range ever.

Comment: Couldn't you just use an entire column range (i.e. `A:A` and `C:C`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub MatchNSort()
Dim lastrow As Long

    'Tell Excel to skip the calculation of all cells and the screen
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Find the last row in the data
    With ActiveSheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lastrow = 1
        End If
    End With

    'Force a formula in column B to match a from c
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & lastrow).Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(C[-1],C[1]:C[1],0)>0,C[-1],""""),"""")"

    'Force a recalculate
    Application.Calculate

    'Sort columns B and A
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Select
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear

        'First key sorts column B
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B" & lastrow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        'Second key (optional) sort column A, after defering to column B
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A" & lastrow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .Sort.SetRange Range("A1:B" & lastrow)
        .Sort.Header = xlGuess
        .Sort.MatchCase = False
        .Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Sort.Apply

    End With

    'Return autocalulation and screen updates
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculate

End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! It's a little slow, but it does the job well. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think that the middle `Application.Calculate` might be unnecessary.  Remove it and see if there is any noticeable improvement.

Answer (score 0):

See [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920) for the best way to find the last row of data.

Find the last row and then change your range selection to:

```
Range("C1:C"&Trim(CStr(lastrow)))
```

To speed up your macro execution start your macro with:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and to restore autocalc and screen updates, end your macro with:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculate
```

Comment: I think I see where you're trying to point me, but I'm new to VBA. I'm unsure how this solves my problem and I'm unsure what it accomplishes :/ Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your problem, I would approach the solution differently.  Since you mentioned that you were happy with your macros, I left them alone.  Let me post a separate, more involved answer on how I would approach a solution.

Comment: Definitely don't let me convince you I'm happy with my macros . . . they get the job done, but it's ugly and slow, and I don't want to have to define the range.